# What is x = zscore(x')' mean in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a piece of code that needs to translate to python.
In matlab, there is a line of code,
x = zscore(x')';
What is this single quote used for?

If I remove it, I get a different result. I do not find any information about this on internet so far.

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/zscore.html) ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen of course, but where it is in that document?

Comment: The `'` is complex-conjugate transpose. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo ,  Thanks, this is the answer. This code first transpose x, then compute zscore, then transpose back.

Comment: You can type `help '` in MATLAB to read the documentation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo , I know Matlab transpose operator ' , However, if it combines in the form of ')' , this extremely confuse me. I just think it is some special, wierd grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a breakdown of the statement by reverse order of evaluation:

- `x = ...` - Assignment.
- `...'`- [Complex conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) of the argument (which operates on the output of `zscore`).
- `zscore(...)` - Computation of the [z-score](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/zscore.html) for a normal distribution of mean 0 and stdev of 1.
- `x'` - Again, complex conjugate transpose of `x`.